# Automated label tagging in figure? Automated labeling?

Tags: floats

Is there a way to set a figure label based on the basename of the eps file used?

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/MYFIGNAMEXXX.eps}
  \caption{my caption} 
  \label{fig:MYFIGNAMEXXX}
\end{figure}
```

This pattern repeats itself at least 15 to 20 times in my document, so what is a convenient way to program/compile this support in?  Probably just a touch beyond my Latex competence.

Edit: @texenthusiast referred to a useful snippet of code by @MMM: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116843/15717

This answer generally captures what I want so far.  From the looks of this code,
how can I take this code snippet to only consider the basename (no folder name or eps extension)?

Edit 2: @Fran provided an excellent answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123511/33383 so far!

Comment: Related: Based on `figure's file name as label` see MMM's answer to [global relabeling of all figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116843/15717)

Comment: I use `pdflatex` and therefore my images are not `.eps`, but propably you can omit safely the extension. That work at least with `.png`, `.jpg` or `.pdf` images.

Comment: @Fran I see, I was able to omit the extension without issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See how the new command `\fig` is defined here to do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove demo for real images! 

\newcommand\fig[2]{
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/#1}
  \caption{#2} 
  \label{fig:#1}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\fig{MYFIGNAME001}{my caption} % 
\fig{MYFIGNAME002}{my other caption} % 

See figures \ref{fig:MYFIGNAME001} and \ref{fig:MYFIGNAME002}

\end{document}
```

Result show that labels are recognized correctly by `\ref` commands:

[image: MWE]

Comment: I think this captures what I want, how would I insert another argument for adjusting the width? set `width=#3` and include another argument? And `fig[2]` to `fig[3]`?

Comment: @KevinLee: `\newcommand\fig[3][.8\textwidth]{...\includegraphics[width=#1]{figures/#2}\caption{#3}\label{fig:#2}...}`

Comment: @KevinLee, You caught the idea `;-)` Up to nine (for more you will need another tricks)

Comment: @Werner Good point suggest a default width

Comment: I'd suggest something like `\newcommand\fig[3][scale=1]{
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[#1]{figures/#2}
  \caption{#3} 
  \label{fig:#2}
\end{figure}
}` which gives the possibility to use in the first optional argument not only `width`, but all the other keys known to `\includegraphics`, and if not used, maintains the natural size of the image.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, good point also, but in my practice rarely the natural size of the images is the good one. For me a better default could be some fixed limits as   `[width=.8\textwidth,height=.4\textwidth,keepaspectratio]`

Answer (score 7):

Preserving as much as possible the `figure` syntax, here's a way with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo just for the example

\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}

% save a copy of \includegraphics
\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro\ORGincludegraphics\includegraphics}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{autofigure}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {\figure[#1]}
   {\figure}
  \cs_set_eq:NN \includegraphics \kevinincludegraphics
 }
 {
  \label{fig:\l_kevin_figurename_tl}
  \endfigure
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\kevinincludegraphics}{O{}m}
 {
  \kevin_include_graphics:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kevin_include_graphics:nn #1 #2
 {
  % split the path into components
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_kevin_path_seq { / } { #2 }
  % get the last component (file name)
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_kevin_path_seq \l_kevin_figurename_tl
  \ORGincludegraphics[#1]{#2}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_kevin_path_seq
\tl_new:N \l_kevin_figurename_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{autofigure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/MYFIGNAMEXXX}
  \caption{my caption} 
\end{autofigure}

\begin{autofigure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{figures/chap1/MYFIGNAMEYYY}
  \caption{my caption} 
\end{autofigure}

Figures \ref{fig:MYFIGNAMEXXX} and \ref{fig:MYFIGNAMEYYY}

\end{document}
```

You can have the path as complex as you want. Don't add the extension, which isn't recommended anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using [easyfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/easyfig), Hope this is what you are looking for...

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe % For loading the example-image-X figures
\usepackage{easyfig} % http://ctan.org/pkg/easyfig
\usepackage{hyperref} % Loading order is important: cleveref after hyperref  
\usepackage{cleveref} % Automatic referencing with "\Cref" to get "Figure" Number
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section*{Fig:label as figure-name : An example}

Autocompletion of \Cref{fig:example-image-a} might not work
in some \TeX{} editors as explicit label command is not 
defined and figure environment is missing. 

\Figure[width=4cm,placement=h,caption={An image}]{example-image-a}

The default figure is centered image. Incase you are 
interested more options in \textit{easyfig} package, have a 
look at its documentation in \textit{texdoc easyfig} on \TeX{}Live 
or ctan website

\Figure[width=4cm,placement=h,caption={An image}]{example-image-b}

Just a second image from \textit{mwe} package for referencing    
\Cref{fig:example-image-b} second image. Another third image 
\Cref{fig:example-image-c} to fill the space

\Figure[width=4cm,placement=h,caption={An image}]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image]